# API Speech to text credentials in google cloud problem

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to use the API Speech to text in google cloud. I try to give the command under as indicated  in the  documentation. I've given the value of GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as
 "D:\certs\My First Project.json" The command is:

```
requests>curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer 
"$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) 
https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize -d @sync-request.json
```

Which results in:

```
requests>curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize -d @sync-request.json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Then I tried the command cloud auth by it self:

```
requests>gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

resulting in:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.application-default.print-access-token) File "D:\certs\My First Project.json" (pointed by GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable) does not exist!
```

What is the problem with my credentials?

Comment: If we look at the last message we see an error that the file does not exist.  Check, check and double check that the file does indeed exist at that location.  If it does ... try a version of the file without space (as a guess).

Comment: Thanks Kolban, I've actually done as you  suggested several times including renaming and have it in a path  without spaces.

Comment: Can it be something to do the Credentials them selves?

Comment: Try copying the file to the C drive root (i.e. c:\mycreds.json).  What if you open notepad on the file .. .does it open?  What if you try reversing the slash markers or escpaing the slashes with double slashes?

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it, you should not have quotes around the [PATH]/[FILENAME] given for GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.
ie

```
SET GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:\home\myfile.json
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that your OS is not finding your credential, the official documentation mentioned how to set  your environment variable [GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-gcloud#before_you_begin).

I also suggest to avoid spaces in the path which contains the KEYFILE.json, as is mentioned in the comments. Let me know how it works.